# [pine-script], is there a way to "monitor" the duration of a "fired" alert?

Tags: pine-script

### for a strategy, is there a way to "monitor" the duration of a "fired" alert?

1. for a strategy, can i monitor an alert, and create a buy/sell (or long condition/short condition), based on the period of time (bars?) since that alert was fired?.
   for example: buy/sell "order" will only accrue after an alert is up for 8 hours straight or two consecutive daily candles, etc.
2. can i create a timestamp for an alert? (start /end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your alert in your strategy script is always triggered by some condition, you can create
some `var` variable, and store `time` where this alert condition was true.

```
var int alert_last_trigger_time = na

if alert_condition 
    alert( .....)
    alert_last_trigger_time := time

duration = time - alert_last_trigger_time
```

And then you can check if is your duration < than 8 hours to enter in position